# How to improve Bluetooth transmit power and throughput with ESP32

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, throughput

I installed the sample programs of ble_spp_server and ble_spp_client on the two ESP32-DEVKITCs respectively, and communicating between those devices.
In the case of sending a large amount of data from the server to the client at once when the radio wave condition is bad, we are in trouble because of data omission.
Is there any way to increase the Bluetooth transmission output and throughput?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a ESP32-DevKitC-32UE with an IPEX connection, add an external IPEX antenna. There are various tutorials on how to connect it. [This one is for an ESP32-CAM](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-connect-external-antenna/), but it should be a similar process. If you only have access to the PCB antenna, and it's not sufficient, you probably will need to get a different board that accepts an external antenna.